# I want to use android SIP API

Tags: android, sip

How can I use android the SIP API?
Can anyone give an example of that please?

Answer (score 1):

use Sip2Sip.info for free sip Id and android native 2.3 api spiDemo to check out the very basic of Sip app.
You might need to add proxy server in code get id registered.